# Android Studio - Qt platform plugin

Tags: android, qt, android-studio, gradle

Пытаюсь запустить AVD Android Studio (ОС Ubuntu)
При запуске выдается следующий стек трейс:

`Emulator: Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.`

`Emulator: ((null):0, (null))`

`Emulator: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)`

Не могу понять, это gradle какую-то зависимость не подключил или же в ОС отсутствует дополнительный плагин? Пробовал установить qt с помощью команды

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxcb-xinerama0` - не помогло

Answer (score 0):

1. попробуйте проанализировать как студия ресолвит либы:

   ldd /путь/к/исполняемому/файлу/студии

возможно поможет понять чего хочет и не находит.

2. попробуйте сделать линк на платформ-плагины:

   sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/